# Why is mongodb updating or upserting instead of inserting?

Tags: mongodb, upsert

I'm inserting a lot of test records in a mongodb instance, via a mongo shell script.

I use batch inserts for performance `db.messages.save(messagesBatch);`

However, mongo upsert or update my data instead of inserting it !

After cleaning the collection, I run a loop for 200 inserts, via batches of 50. I end up with 51 (??) records after 4 batches, with following reports from `db.getLastErrorObj()`:

```javascript
/* 0 */
{
"n" : 0,
"connectionId" : 166,
"err" : null,
"ok" : 1
}

/* 1 */
{
"updatedExisting" : false,
"upserted" : ObjectId("527141c72a1ae75210d3a705"),
"n" : 1,
"connectionId" : 166,
"err" : null,
"ok" : 1
}

/* 2 */
{
"updatedExisting" : true,
"n" : 1,
"connectionId" : 166,
"err" : null,
"ok" : 1
}

/* 3 */
{
"updatedExisting" : true,
"n" : 1,
"connectionId" : 166,
"err" : null,
"ok" : 1
}
```

my insertion code is the following :

```javascript
var batchLimit = 50;
var messagesBatch = [];

function flushMessages() {
print("* flushing... (" + messagesBatch.length + ")");
var inserted = false; // so far
do {
    db.messages.save(messagesBatch);
    var errObj = db.getLastErrorObj();
    print(errObj);
    if(errObj.ok && errObj.err === null) {
        // no error, fine
        inserted = true;
        messagesBatch.length = 0;
        print("* flushed. (" + messagesBatch.length + ")");
    }
    else {
        // insertion error !
        failedInsertions++;
        print(errObj);
    }
} while(!inserted);
}

function addMessage(message) {
messagesBatch.push(message);
if(messagesBatch.length >= batchLimit) {
    flushMessages();
}
msgGenerated++;
if(msgGenerated % 100000 == 0)
    print("* " + msgGenerated);
}
```

Can someone see why this code is upserting instead of inserting ? What am I doing wrong ?

Note : of course, the documents I'm inserting don't have an `_id` field.

Comment: Can you show some sample messages?

Comment: @ithcy I'd rather not (company data) but they don't have an `_id` field, though they have a bunch of `xyzID` fields.

Comment: Save will do an upsert if the document contains an _id field.

Comment: @Martin which they have not (unless I made an error somewhere) and how do you explain the strange 51 ? All records are created from scratch via `new XYZ()` which doesn't set an `_id` field.

Comment: You're doing (trying to do) 200 inserts total - the final count of inserted records could be anywhere from 0 to 200, no?

Comment: @ithcy yes, and I expect 200 and I check for errors with `db.getLastErrorObj();` Did you see the returned errObjs in my question ? They clearly say `updatedExisting: true` but why ?

Comment: @Offirmo what I meant was 51 is not an impossible result... it does suggest that your process is stopping after 1 batch + 1 record, though.

Comment: @itchy however I correctly get 4 (200/50) traces and 4 reports

Comment: Have you inspected the 51 inserts to see if they relate to any one particular batch of records?

Comment: @ithcy yes they're all from the first batch, but the 51th is empty --> that is strange ! I'm inspecting subsequent batches before insertion and they contain correct data...

Comment: It seems it comes from using the `messagesBatch.length = 0;` technique for emptying the array. When "reseting" (sort of) by creating a new array with `messagesBatch = [];` it works as expected. I can't explain why since I'm waiting for getLastErrorObj. Or is the insertion asynchronous ? Then it should insert no records at all. (The empty 51th record comes from a bad systematic "safety" flushing of an empty array at the end of the script and is not related to the problem)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems it comes from using the `messagesBatch.length = 0;` technique for emptying the array to prepare the next batch. When instead "reseting" (sort of) by creating a new array with `messagesBatch = [];` it works as expected.

I guess the insertion is asynchronous and works directly on the array ref, **and** it seems that waiting for getLastErrorObj() is not enough to be sure that all data has been written. This seems wrong.

The empty 51th record came from a bad systematic "safety" flushing of an empty array at the end of the script and was not related to the problem.